# Rails, SQL: private chat, how to find last message in each conversation

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3

I'v got the folowing schema

```
+----+------+------+-----------+---------------------+--------+
| id | from | to   | message   | timestamp           | readed |
+----+------+------+-----------+---------------------+--------+
| 46 |    2 |    6 | 123       | 2013-11-19 19:12:19 |      0 |
| 44 |    2 |    3 | 123       | 2013-11-19 19:12:12 |      0 |
| 43 |    2 |    1 | ????????? | 2013-11-19 18:37:11 |      0 |
| 42 |    1 |    2 | adf       | 2013-11-19 18:37:05 |      0 |
+----+------+------+-----------+---------------------+--------+
```

from/to is the ID of the user's, message – obviously, the message, timestamp and read flag.
When user open's his profile I want him to see the list of dialogs he participated with last message in this dialog.
To find a conversation between 2 people I wrote this code, it's simple (Message model):

```
def self.conversation(from, to)
  where(from: [from, to], to: [from, to])
end
```

So, I can now sort the messages and get the last one. But it's not cool to fire a lot of queries for each dialog.
How could I achieve the result I'm looking for with less queries?

**UPDATE**:

Ok, looks like it's not really clear, what I'm trying to achieve.
For example, 4 users – Kitty, Dandy, Beggy and Brucy used that chat.
When Brucy entered in dialogs, she shall see

```
Beggy: hello brucy haw ar u! | <--- the last message from beggy
------- 
Dandy: Hi brucy! | <---- the last message from dandy
--------
Kitty: Hi Kitty, my name is Brucy! | <–– this last message is from current user
```

So, three separated dialogs. Then, Brucy can enter anyone dialog to continue private conversation.
And I can't figured out how could I fetch this records without firing a query for each dialog between users.

Comment: fetch messages, sort with timestamp in decending, get the first message.. thats the last one.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is a bit late, but there doesn't seem to be a great way to do this, in Rails 3.2.x at least.

However, here is the solution I came up with
(as I had the same problem on my website).

```
  @sender_ids =
    Message.where(recipient_id: current_user.id)
           .order("created_at DESC")
           .select("DISTINCT owner_id")
           .paginate(per_page: 10, page: params[:page])
  sql_queries =
    @sender_ids.map do |user|
      user_id = user.owner_id
      "(SELECT * FROM messages WHERE owner_id = #{user_id} "\
      "AND recipient_id = #{current_user.id} ORDER BY id DESC "\
      "LIMIT 1)"
    end.join(" UNION ALL ")

  @messages = Message.find_by_sql(sql_queries)
  ActiveRecord::Associations::Preloader.new(@messages, :owner).run
```

This gets the last 10 unique people you sent messages to.
For each of those people, it creates a UNION ALL query to get the last message sent to each of those 10 unique people. With 50, 000 rows, the query completes in about ~20ms. And of course to get assocations to preload, you have to use `.includes` will not work when using `.find_by_sql`

Answer (score -1):

```
def self.conversation(from, to)
  order("timestamp asc").last
end
```

**Edit:**

This railscast will be helpful..

http://railscasts.com/episodes/316-private-pub?view=asciicast

**EDIT2:**

```
def self.conversation(from, to)
    select(:from, :to, :message).where(from: [from, to], to: [from, to]).group(:from, :to, :country).order("timestamp DESC").limit(1)
end
```

Comment: I'm added some update – i need not the latest record, i need the latest record in pair from-to.

Comment: Not really: the problem isn't in creating live webchat – I'm already created it with NodeJS & Socket.IO, but in displaying last messages of each conversation by native rails functionality only.